# How to get a child in an n-way tree?

Tags: c++, tree

I have an n-way tree implemented using std::vector.  The Node class holds just the pointer to the root element and the Link class has an std::vector of pointers to itself.  I'm naming each of my links when I create them but when I try to locate a node in this tree using the name of the link but get a segmentation fault. Also I realize the my function GetLink() doesn't do any error checking, I tried a couple of things but they didn't work so if possible any suggestion on how to implement that in this case would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
// in node.h
class Node {
public:
 // constructors
 // fuctions
private:
 Link *root;
};

// in link.h
class Link {
public:
//EDIT: added vector initialization in the constructor
 Link() : my_links(0) { }
 // some functions
 // EDIT: example of making the tree
 bool Load(token) {
 // parsing code based on token
   else if (strcmp (temp, "link") == 0)
   {
        Link* lnk = new Link ();
        lnk->Load (token);
        lnk->Init ();
        AddChild (lnk);
        lnk->m_parent = this;
   }
    // some more parsing code
 }
 void Link::AddChild (Link* pChild)
 {
   my_links.push_back(pChild);
 }

 Link* Link::GetLink(char* str)  // this is the function that is the problem.
 {
   if (strcmp(name, str) == 0)
   {
     return this;
   }

   for (int i=0; i < (int) my_links.size(); i++)
   {
    //Edit: added check for NULL ptr
     if (my_links[i] == NULL)
     {
        fprintf (stderr, "\n\t Couldn't find link\n\n");
        break;
     } 
     //Edit: typo corrected
     return my_links[i]->GetLink(str);
   }
 }

private:
 char name[256];
 Link* m_parent;
 std::vector<Link*> my_links;
};

// in main.cpp
static Node* node;
static Link* link;
main()
{
  char *str = "link_3";
  link = node->GetLink(str);
  printf("\n found link: %s", link->GetName());
  retrun 0;
}
```

EDIT: Rewriting earlier code as an MCVE

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

class Link {
public:
//EDIT: added vector initialization in the constructor
 Link() : my_links(0)
 {
   m_parent = NULL;
 }

 void SetParent(Link* pParent)
 {
   m_parent = pParent;
 }

 // EDIT: example of making the tree
 bool Load(char *str)
 {
        unsigned int len;
        Link* lnk = new Link ();
        len = strlen(str);
        strcpy(name, str);
        lnk->SetParent(this);
        AddChild (lnk);
        return true;
 }

 void AddChild (Link* pChild)
 {
   my_links.push_back(pChild);
 }

 Link* GetLink(char* str)  // this is the function that is the problem.
 {
   if (strcmp(name, str) == 0)
   {
     return this;
   }

   for (int i=0; i < (int) my_links.size(); i++)
   {
    //Edit: added check for NULL ptr
     if (my_links[i] == NULL)
     {
        fprintf (stderr, "\n\t Couldn't find link\n\n");
        break;
     }
     //Edit: typo corrected
     return my_links[i]->GetLink(str);
   }
   fprintf(stderr, "\n\t Cannot get link\n\n");
   return 0;
 }

 char* GetName()
 {
   return name;
 }

private:
 char name[256];
 Link* m_parent;
 std::vector<Link*> my_links;
};


class Node {
public:
 Node()
 {
    root = NULL;
 }

 bool Load (char *str)
 {
    unsigned int len;
    root = new Link();  // here is where the error occurs
    len = strlen(str);
    strcpy(name, str);
    return true;
 }

 void AddChild (char *str)
 {
   root->Load(str);
 }

 Link* GetRoot()
 {
   return root;
 }

private:
 char name[256];
 Link *root;
};

static Node* node;
static Link* lnk;
int main()
{
  node->Load((char*)"I am root");
  node->AddChild((char*)"I am child 1");
  node->AddChild((char*)"I am child 2");
  node->AddChild((char*)"I am child 3");
  char *str = (char*)"I am child 2";
  lnk = node->GetRoot()->GetLink(str);
  printf("\n found link: %s", lnk->GetName());
  return 0;
}
```

Error I get now in VS2010 on Line 77 which is the "root = new Link()" in the Node class, Load() function is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x012e1bbe in nWayTree.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000100.
```

Comment: If you're using `std::vector`, it isn't C that you're writing, so don't tag your question with C.

Comment: You have not initialized the size of the `vector`. Either `push_back` all the `Link` pointers, or initialize the size of the `vector` in the constructor. Hence, `my_links.size()` gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: @ShauryaChats I am initializing vector in the constructor and have a function that adds children by pushing_back I just didn't include it here for brevity.

Comment: seems like the memory management is going to be a pain. use boost::optional in your vector, or boost::any. Or smart pointers, like `unique_ptr`. This will free you from having to care manually about RAII.

Comment: Okay. Also, I think you should try adding a terminating condition in the `GetLink()`  for a `Link*` being equal to `NULL`.

Comment: @ShauryaChats I made the edits in the code, one for the constructor and one for the NULL ptr check; however, I still get segmentation fault for some reason.

Comment: Can you show a simple example, how you create your tree?

Comment: You don't return the result of the recursive call to GetLink. Is this a copy paste error?

Comment: @MikeMD Yes, thanks for noticing the return typo, I'll make the edit, also in regard to your earlier question I made the edit to show how I build the tree when parsing the file.

Comment: Please post a MCVE that actually produces your error.

Comment: Are you sure, your return statement is inside the loop?

Comment: @MikeMB Sorry for getting back to you so late, I went to sleep last night before I saw your comments.  I tried rewriting the code as MCVE as you requested, it still doesn't work but now I get a linker error as opposed to a segmentation fault.  I posted the new code with the error output as an edit at the bottom of my initial code.  In regards to your other question, I checked and the return is in the loop just as it is in the code in the post.

Comment: @MikeMB Just fixed the linker error that was due to Load() not returning anything but it look like I'm back to the seg fault, at least now it is in the MCVE format.

Comment: No problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the error in the MCVE is that you never instantiate `node` and as a result, `node->Load((char*)"I am root");` dereferences an uninitialized pointer resulting in undefined behavior. Effectively, you get an access violation, when your program tries to write to the memory location where it expects the 'root' member variable to live. You could fix this, by writing

```
static Node* node = new Node();
```

However, even after fixing this error, your MCVE still has semantic errors. Every time you call `node->AddChild` you don't add another child, but you rename your node and assign a new default constructed link (without a name) to the `root` member variable of node. Also your GetLink() function doesn't recursively call GetLink() on all children (if there were any), but only calls GetLink() on the first child and then returns the result unconditionally (the loop is executed AT MOST ONCE).

Also the distinction between, Node, Link and root is not quite clear to me. Here is, what I assume you want to achieve, with as little additional c++ (compared to your example) as possible:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

class Node {
private:
    char m_name[256];
    Node* m_parent;
    std::vector<Node*> my_links;
public:
    //EDIT: added vector initialization in the constructor
    Node(const char* name, Node* parent=nullptr) : m_parent(parent), my_links() {
        strcpy(m_name, name);
    }

    void AddChild(const char* childname) {
        my_links.push_back(new Node(childname,this));
    }

    Node* GetNode(const char* str)  {
        if (strcmp(m_name, str) == 0)   {
            return this;
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < my_links.size(); i++) 
        { 
            Node* t = my_links[i]->GetNode(str); 
            if (t != NULL) return t; 
        } 
        return NULL; 

    }

    char* GetName() {
        return m_name;
    }
};

Node root((const char*)"I am root");

int main()
{
    root.AddChild("I am child 1");
    root.AddChild("I am child 2");
    root.AddChild("I am child 3");  
    const char *str1 = "I am child 2";
    const char *str2 = "I am child 1 of child 2 of root";
    root.GetNode(str1)->AddChild(str2);
    Node* node = root.GetNode(str2);
    if (node == NULL) {
        printf("Link not found");
    } else
    {
        printf("\n found link: %s", node->GetName());
    }
}
```

And here is a "modern c++ style" version (not claiming it is a particular good one):

EDIT: I just realized that you are using VS2010, which will fail to compile the following example, because it uses some c++11 and c++14 (current c++ standard) features. However, you can built it with the free version of VS2013 and should be able to built it with any recent version of g++ and clang++ (you'll have to add the flag '-std=c++14' or similar though).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Node {
private:
    string m_name;
    Node* m_parent;
    vector<unique_ptr<Node>> my_links;

public: 
    Node(const string& name, Node* parent = nullptr) : 
        m_name(name),
        m_parent(parent), 
        my_links()
    {}

    void AddChild(const string& childname) {
        my_links.push_back(make_unique<Node>(childname, this));
    }

    Node* GetNode(const string& str)  {
        if (m_name == str)  {
            return this;
        } 
        for (auto& e:my_links) 
        { 
            Node* t = e->GetNode(str);
            if (t != nullptr) return t; 
        } 
        return nullptr;         
    }

    string GetName()    {
        return m_name;
    }
};

Node root("I am root");

int main()
{
    root.AddChild("I am child 1");
    root.AddChild("I am child 2");
    root.AddChild("I am child 3");
    string str1("I am child 2");
    string str2("I am child 1 of child 2 of root");
    root.GetNode(str1)->AddChild(str2);
    Node* node = root.GetNode(str2);
    if (node == nullptr) {
        cout <<"Link not found";
    } else  {
        cout << "found link: "<< node->GetName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also have VS2013 so that's no problem, appreciate your help.